# Retrofit 2.6.2 is not working on Vodafone mobile data but works fine on WiFi

Tags: android, android-studio, networking, retrofit, retrofit2.6

Please help me Some of my app users are complaining or giving feedback that their app doesn't work on mobile data **(Vodafone 4G)** but works on wifi.

I am using **Retrofit-2.6.2** and **okhttp3 - 4.2.2.**

```
Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl(baseurl)
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
    .client(getClient())
    .build()

fun getClient(): OkHttpClient {
    return OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(HeaderIntercepter())
        .readTimeout(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
        .writeTimeout(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
        .connectTimeout(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
        .build()
}
```

APIs are made on **Amazon server** using *http and https* both.

What are the things missing from my side please give me solution?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is some **4G network issues** here Like in Vodafone Network. The connection time in this network for **TCP connecting** which is ***connectTimeout*** is always connecting so the api is not able connect before ***2 mins*** because timeout is mentioned of ***2 mins***

So, I solve this by reducing the TCP connecting time which is **connectTimeout to 1sec**, here is the code :

```
OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .addInterceptor(HeaderIntercepter())
        .callTimeout(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
        .connectTimeout(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .readTimeout(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
        .writeTimeout(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
        .build()
```

If you api or url not needs the **TCP connection between data sending and receiving through retrofit** then you can do like this, working fine for me now.

Answer (score 0):

Add `network-security-config` to res/xml folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <network-security-config>
      <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
       <trust-anchors>
        <certificates src="system" />
       </trust-anchors>
      </base-config>
    </network-security-config>
```

Add a line in `manifest` file `application` tag

```
android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
```

And make sure you give `internet` permission in `manifest` file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Also add this in `manifest` file

```
 <uses-library
        android:name="org.apache.http.legacy"
        android:required="false"/>
```

add `useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'` in your app build gradle

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "your_application_id"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
```

Comment: @DeePanShu try using `legacy` hope this work for you

Comment: taking 2 much time to load around 2-3 minutes first time after that works perfectly